Scriban - Search Result template
i have requirement to implement the Related Article to show in the article page. I have used the SXA search result OOTB component to get the result.
Here is the design. I have the condition to display the html in the page. If the first article contain the image i want to separate the col like col-md-7 and col-md-5 if not i need only col-md-5 column only. I have tried the scriban but that is not working.


Can you paste the scriban that you are using to achieve the results?

In order to customize the html for search result component in SXA, you will need to edit the component-search-results.js located at below location inside Base Theme folder.
/sitecore/media library/Base Themes/SearchTheme/Scripts/component-search-results

Html defined for each list item inside the rendering variant in search component is computed and send to the browser through API Response as below. This html response is then rendered in DOM using Backbone template.

Therefore in order to meet your requirement, you can edit the Backbone template inside the SearchResultModel as below.
defaults: {
   template: "<% if(!results.length){ %><div class='no-results'><%= noResultsText %></div> <% }else { %>" +
    "<% if(imageExist) { %> <div class='col-md-7'><img src='<%= imageURL %>'/></div>"  + 
    "<ul class='search-result-list'> " +
    "<% _.forEach(results, function(result){ %>" +
     "<li " + "<% if(result.Geospatial){%>data-id='<%= result.Id %>' data-longitude='<%= result.Geospatial.Longitude %>' data-latitude='<%= result.Geospatial.Latitude %>'<% } %>" + "><%= result.Html %></li>" +
    "<% }); %>" +
    "</ul>" +
    "<% } else { %>" +
    "<ul class='search-result-list'> " +
    "<% _.forEach(results, function(result){ %>" +
    "<li " + "<% if(result.Geospatial){%>data-id='<%= result.Id %>' data-longitude='<%= result.Geospatial.Longitude %>' data-latitude='<%= result.Geospatial.Latitude %>'<% } %>" + "><%= result.Html %></li>" +
    "<% }); %>" +
    "</ul>" +
    "<% }  %>" + 
    "<% } %>" +
    "<div class='search-result-overlay'>",
  }

You will need to pass the parameters imageExist and imageUrl in the render function when the template is initialized.
render: function () {
  var imageExist = // logic to decide whether the first article contains image.
  var imageUrl = // url for the first image.
  var templateResult = template({ results: results, noResultsText: inst.model.get("noResultsText"),imageExist: imageExist, imageUrl:imageUrl   });
  this.$el.html(templateResult);
}


Using this way, you can successfully meet the requirements for your case. Make sure you are creating the new js for making these changes rather than changing the one inside the base theme.
Hope this helps!! Let me know in case you face any issues.
